# Simple Tag Parser

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

This is a model of a forgiving HTML parser. Instead of parsing HTML and extracting attributes, in this code golf, the tag parser will be simple.

Write a function that parses a tag structure and returns its parenthized form.
An opening tag consists of one lowercase letter, and a closing tag consists of one uppercase letter. For example, `aAbaAB` parses into `(a)(b(a))`, or in HTML, `<a></a><b><a></a></b>`.
Of course, tags can be in juxtaposition and nest.

"Prematurely" closed tags must be handled. For example, in `abcA`, the `A` closes the outermost `a`, so it parses into `(a(b(c)))`.

Extra closing tags are simply ignored: `aAB` parses into `(a)`.

Overlapping tags are NOT handled. For example, `abAB` parses into `(a(b))`, not `(a(b))(b)`, by the previous rule of extra closing tags (`abAB` -> `abA` (`(a(b))`) + `B` (extra)).

Assuming no whitespaces and other illegal characters in the input.

You are not allowed to use any library.

Here is a reference implementation and a list of test cases:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def pars(inpu):
  outp = ""
  stac = []
  i = 0
  for x in inpu:
    lowr = x.lower()
    if x == lowr:
      stac.append(x)
      outp += "(" + x
      i = i + 1
    else:
      while len(stac) > 1 and stac[len(stac) - 1] != lowr:
        outp += ")"
        stac.pop()
        i = i - 1
      if len(stac) > 0:
        outp += ")"
        stac.pop()
        i = i - 1
  outp += ")" * i
  return outp

tests = [
  ("aAaAbB", "(a)(a)(b)"),
  ("abBcdDCA", "(a(b)(c(d)))"),
  ("bisSsIB", "(b(i(s)(s)))"),
  ("aAabc", "(a)(a(b(c)))"),
  ("abcdDA", "(a(b(c(d))))"),
  ("abcAaA", "(a(b(c)))(a)"),
  ("acAC", "(a(c))"),
  ("ABCDEFG", ""),
  ("AbcBCabA", "(b(c))(a(b))")
]

for case, expe in tests:
  actu = pars(case)
  print "%s: C: [%s] E: [%s] A: [%s]" % (["FAIL", "PASS"][expe == actu], case, expe, actu)
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: like any other code golfs, standard library allowed

Comment: no limit on length nor nesting level

Comment: You should add a test case for input that leads with a closing tag, such as `AbcBCabA` (should parse as `(b(c))(a(b))`. My code could have been shorter except for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Golfscript, 54 chars

```
{[]:|\{.96>{.|+:|;40\}{32+|?).')'*\|>:|;}if}%|,')'*}:$
```

Tests

```
;["aAaAbB" "abBcdDCA" "bisSsIB" "aAabc" "abcdDA" "abcAaA" "acAC" "aAB" "abAB" "AbcBCabA"]{.' '\$n}%

aAaAbBaAaAbB (a)(a)(b)
abBcdDCA (a(b)(c(d)))
bisSsIB (b(i(s)(s)))
aAabc (a)(a(b(c)))
abcdDA (a(b(c(d))))
abcAaA (a(b(c)))(a)
acAC (a(c))
aAB (a)
abAB (a(b))
AbcBCabA (b(c))(a(b))
```

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 111 characters

```
s@(d:z)§c|c>'^'=toEnum(fromEnum c-32):s++'(':[c]|d<'='=s|d==c=z++")"|1<3=(z++")")§c
p=tail.foldl(§)"$".(++"$")
```

This one's pretty golf'd for Haskell. Fun feature: The stack and the accumulating output are kept in the same string!

Test cases:

```
> runTests 
Pass: aAbaAB parsed correctly as (a)(b(a))
Pass: abcA parsed correctly as (a(b(c)))
Pass: aAB parsed correctly as (a)
Pass: abAB parsed correctly as (a(b))
Pass: aAaAbB parsed correctly as (a)(a)(b)
Pass: abBcdDCA parsed correctly as (a(b)(c(d)))
Pass: bisSsIB parsed correctly as (b(i(s)(s)))
Pass: aAabc parsed correctly as (a)(a(b(c)))
Pass: abcdDA parsed correctly as (a(b(c(d))))
Pass: abcAaA parsed correctly as (a(b(c)))(a)
Pass: acAC parsed correctly as (a(c))
Pass: AbcBCabA parsed correctly as (b(c))(a(b))
```

---

- Edit: (113 → 111) used an `@` pattern as suggested by FUZxxl

Comment: Using an @-pattern for d:z might save two chars.

Answer (score 5):

## Z80 Machine Code for TI-83+, 41 bytes

This is an implementation in hexadecimal machine code for a z80 cpu running on a TI-83+.

`11XXXX131AFE61380F6FE53E28CD9DB47DCD9DB4188EE1BDC03E29CD9DB4189BEF4504E5214CE1C9`

The XXXX (3 - 6 inclusive) is the 16-bit address of the string you are parsing, minus 1 byte.

Encoded in Z80-ASCII:

`¹XX≤¯•⟙8o↥>(ˣïÑ}ˣïÑ≠á↑γ∊>)ˣïÑ≠Ì⬆︎E↥!₄L↑Φ`

(Approximate, because TI calculators have their own character set.)

NOTE THAT THE `AsmPrgm` IS NOT INCLUDED IN THE ABOVE

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PowerShell, 142 <s>146</s> <s>147</s> <s>152</s> <s>156</s> <s>169</s>

```
{$s=''
-join([char[]]"$args "|%{if(90-ge$_){')'*(($x=$s.indexOf("$_".ToLower())+1)+$s.Length*!$x)
$s=$s.substring($x)}else{"($_"
$s="$_$s"}})}
```

Some things to note: This is just a script block. It can be assigned to a variable or given a function name, if necessary. You can also run it by putting `.` or `&` in front of it and the arguments at the end. Uses a final space to terminate unclosed tags.

Passes all tests. Test script:

```
$tests = ("aAaAbB","(a)(a)(b)"),("abBcdDCA","(a(b)(c(d)))"),("bisSsIB","(b(i(s)(s)))"),("aAabc","(a)(a(b(c)))"),("abcdDA","(a(b(c(d))))"),("abcAaA", "(a(b(c)))(a)"),("acAC","(a(c))")
"function f " + ((gc ./tags.ps1)-join"`n") | iex
$tests | %{
    $result = f $_[0]
    ("FAIL: $($_[0]):$($_[1]) - $result", 'PASS')[$result -ceq $_[1]]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python - <strike>114</strike> <strike>113</strike> <strike>153</strike> <strike>192</strike> <strike>174</strike> 159  characters

```
from sys import *
s="";c=a=argv[1]
for f in a:
 o=c.find;p=f.lower
 if '@'<f<'\\':
\td=o(f)-o(p())
\ts+=")"*d
\tc=(c[:o(p())]+c[o(f)+1:])
 else:s+=("("+f)
print s
```

Abuses python's indentation parser to use one space for a full tab, five for two tabs.

**Edit 1** - saved an unneeded space in the range() function

**Edit 2** - fixed to deal with improper parse grammars, unterminated tags.

**Edit 3** - fixed a bug whereby "incorrect" parses could be generated by ambiguity in the tag tree. Implemented a stack-based strategy, rather than a counter.

**Edit 4** - renamed s.find to o to prevent save the chars used to repeatedly call it. did the same for f.lower.

**Edit 5** - added the space/tab hack, saving three chars.

**Edit 6** - ditched the loop in favor of ")"*d.

Comment: instead of `ord(f)...` you can use `'@'<f<'\\'` If you don't need to check for `'\\'` you can use `']'` instead

Comment: you can use a single tab instead of 5 spaces. SO code markup can't handle it though :(. In your case just put leave out the newline and the spaces altogether. eg `if ...:s+=")";c-=1` and `else:s+="("+f;c+=1`

Comment: `for i in range(d):s+=")"` can be rewritten as `s+=")"*d`. And you have 174 chars.

Comment: @cemper - good point that. I do "_"*80 all day long and forget about it when golfing.... Also, thanks to @gnibbler for the suggestions!

Comment: Actually, I meant that you had had 174 chars _before_. So you are at 159 now.

Comment: @cemper93 - good catch, thanks! Proving that I cannot, in fact read.